# custom_id discord-components discord.py

Tags: discord, discord.py, discord-api

в discord-components в кнопках есть custom_id
create_button(
label="Создать карточку", emoji="", custom_id="create_card", style=ButtonStyle.green
)
как в interaction отслеживать по этим айди?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось, чтобы отследить по кастомному айди нужно изменять сам модуль, собственно решил, скоро скину фикс